# Java peer to peer udp chatting room

Tags: java, sockets, udp, p2p

I'm new to Java socket programming and I'm currently developing a small peer to peer UDP chatting room application which allow multiple clients to chat with each other.

My question is how do I make a client discover all other connected clients once he hit the connect button providing only one of the connected clients ip and port? The program only runs on local network.

Comment: I've tried using a list and passing it to every new client.Somehow it didn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a unique feature of UDP which is [broadcasting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Broadcast_address)

On IPv4 (which you are probably using) the address for broadcasting is 255.255.255.255. Any datagram sent to that address will be sent to all UDP clients on the network for that port.

What you can do for your chat application is to have each client send a packet to the UDP broadcast identifying itself, such as maybe the nickname of the user. All the other clients will see that packet, and you will be able to parse the packet and display a list of all the chat clients on the network.

Here is an example of sending a Datagram to broadcast:

```
    DatagramSocket s = new DatagramSocket();
    s.setBroadcast(true);
    DatagramPacket dp = new DatagramPacket("insert data here".getBytes(), "insert data here".length(), new InetSocketAddress("255.255.255.255", 5000));
    s.send(dp);
```

Another client can receive it like this:

```
DatagramSocket s = new DatagramSocket();
s.setBroadcast(true);
DatagramPacket dp = new DatagramPacket(new byte[1024], 1024);
s.receive(dp);
```

The received DatagramPacket will contain the IP and port of the client who had broadcasted it.

Comment: Thank you.I'm going to try this.

Comment: @Omar if you have any questions, let me know.

Answer (score 0):

One simple possibility would be that every client stores the other peers it knows of and passes the list to any new clients connecting.

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget of authenticating your peers. You can try to use the OpenSSL (very easy) to generate some certificates and use it in association to ssl.

Edit: a bot told me to be more specific so here it is:

Local Networks (LANs) are not always safe, so, to be sure, I would recommend you use OpenSSL to generate certificates for authentication and private keys for encryption, in this way, you can communicate safely.
Python ssl module is a good example.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).